# Update query variables from react apanel plugin. Grafana

Tags: reactjs, grafana

I've developed react panel plugin and in this plugin user can select values for time range which will be used in query using variables.

Query example:

```
select * from data where time > '$startDate' and time < '$endDate'
```

I already have a solution using getLocationSrv().update(), but it takes too much time to update variables. And those variables needs to be created before as dashboard variables.

I saw a solution using scopedVars, but this was in angular.
Is there any similar way, how to solve it but in React?

Thanks